# why Flutter Build Runner Don't Working with commands?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, build-runner

i try to make .g file with this commands "flutter pub run build_runner build" and i can't run it.
Error: Exhausted heap space with out of memory while running command

Flutter clean
Flutter pub Get
Flutter Upgrade
Check Flutter doctor

Answer (score 1):

May be This issue was created by white space in project name,Remove it.

Comment: This was my worst problem
Solved, Tnx milad